# Python 3: built-in round(...) function behaving weird. Alternative to Python 2 round in Python 3?

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, rounding

**Python 3**

```
>>> round(1.5)
2
>>> round(2.5)
2
>>> round(3.5)
4
>>> round(4.5)
4
```

I don't understand this. How is `3.5` rounded `4` but `4.5` rounded is not `5`? Is there any way to get the normal way of round where if number is `5` or greater in the `tenths` column (`>0.5`) it will round to the next whole number?

EDIT: In Python 2.7 the `round` function behaved properly.

**Answer** - Credit: [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20862/ignacio-vazquez-abrams).

To retain Python 2 rounding:

```
import math
>>> def old_round(n):
        return math.floor(n + 0.5)

>>> old_round(4.5)
5
```

Comment: Do you know how we get the old round behavior back in Python 3?

Comment: Add 0.5 and floor it.

Comment: `In Python 2.7 the round function behaved properly` According to who? [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) does not agree with you. You can select rounding with the Decimal module if you wish.

Comment: @dawg Sorry, "properly" is wrong wording. I meant that it behaves as we are normally taught in school and life. If 0.5 or above then round up. Most people even today round 0.5 to the next number.